# How Count Number of Records Returned by a SQL Query Using OleDb

Tags: c#, sql, windows, oledbdatareader, jet-engine

Is there an easy way to find the Number of Records returned by a call to the Microsoft OleDbDataReader, reading from an Access Database (JetEngine)?

I want to find the number of different "Teams" (whose Team Number is greater than 0) in the "RoundData" table in my Access database .

The following code correctly returns the Teams with a distinct team number greater than zero.

```
CmdStr = $"SELECT DISTINCT {Team} FROM [RoundData] WHERE {Team} > 0";

ReadCmd = new OleDbCommand( CmdStr, ResultsReportingOleDbConnection );

Reader = ReadCmd.ExecuteReader();
```

I can loop through the records returned, counting the number of them, but all I want is the number of them.

I can't use "SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT...) as the Jet Engine does not support this feature (I believe) .

Is there a SELECT COUNT() ... command string that I can use, I tried the following:-

```
CmdStr = $"SELECT Count() FROM [RoundData] WHERE {Team} = ( SELECT DISTINCT {Team} FROM [RoundData] WHERE {Team} > 0 )";

ReadCmd = new OleDbCommand( CmdStr, ResultsReportingOleDbConnection );

int X = (int)ReadCmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

But received the following error message:-

> At most one record can be returned by this subquery

Comment: Why are the `Team`s being injected, why aisn't uit just one column? Sample data and expected results would help immensely.

Answer (score 0):

Your last try is on the right track but your logic is wrong. I havent tested the syntax in Access but it would be more like this:

```sql
SELECT Count() FROM
(
    SELECT DISTINCT {Team} FROM [RoundData] WHERE {Team} > 0
)
```

In SQL Server you would have to name the subquery result, e.g.

```sql
SELECT Count() FROM
(
    SELECT DISTINCT {Team} FROM [RoundData] WHERE {Team} > 0
) A
```

but I'm not sure that Jet requires that.

You would then call `ExecuteScalar` to get that result value.

Comment: I have tried the solution above, but when I  did I received the following really quite strange error reply:-   "There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first." As far as I am aware, there is not an open 'DataReader', as I had closed the OleDbDataReader in an immediately preceding line of code. Very strange !

Comment: @TonyH, please update the question and show us the new code that generated that error. If you're calling `ExecuteReader` and `ExecuteScalar` then that would be the issue. You just create the command and call `ExecuteScalar`. That method calls `ExecuteReader` internally and reads the first column of the first row.

Comment: Unfortunately I discarded the exact code I was using whilst trying to get the query to work. However I modified your initial answer which did not work, but by adding a "*" to "Count()", the query worked. Thanks for your help

Comment: @TonyH, I copied your original SQL and modified it and didn't notice that omission. I should have checked more thoroughly.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that the following code works:-

```
            CmdStr = $"SELECT Count(*) (FROM SELECT DISTINCT {Direction} FROM [RoundData] WHERE {Direction} > 0)";                                                                          
            ReadCmd = new OleDbCommand( CmdStr, ResultsReportingOleDbConnection );
            int X = (int)ReadCmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

However if I omit the `*` from `Count(*)`, the query fails.